# message queue model for a realtime app

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, real-time, message-queue, apache-kafka

I am building a realtime application that will have mobile devices as the consumers, and server side components. Basically the app relies on external API to fetch the data and once the data is received by the server, it will be distributed to the mobile clients.

I was thinking of using a message queue like Apache Kafka or Rabbitmq to deliver the messages to the connected mobile clients. Once the connected mobile clients receive a message, it needs to be parsed how to react since it's a raw message.

To minimize computing on mobile devices, I would really like to do some sort of computation on server side and send the exact message to mobile clients. But then this requires a topic/channel per mobile client which I am not sure is efficient and if rabbitmq/kafka can handle. Let's say there are 100k consumers (mobile clients) connected at any time.

Is it efficient to have 100k topics/channels with 1 consumer each?

Is using message queue really the right option here?

Comment: It's very unlikely that a mobile device will be able to talk the AMPQ protocol and consume messages directly from RabbitMQ. You might consider [push notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html) instead.

Comment: Maybe using a cloud pub/sub message broker like [Realtime Messaging](http://framework.realtime.co/messaging) (the company I work for) could help.